# Error while converting NetCDF file to data frame in R

Tags: r, error, excel, netcdf

I am trying to convert netcdf files to excel or text files. But when I am using this code:

```
tab<-as.data.frame(brick("mydata.nc"),xy=TRUE,long=FALSE)
```

this error appears:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(object)) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

What do I need to do to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot coerce directly to a data.frame, use getValues() to coerce after you have read in the cdf file.

```
tab <- brick("mydata.nc")
tab.df <- as.data.frame(getValues(tab))
```

Just keep in mind that this is not memory safe and it is likely that you will **not** be able to fit the problem into memory. Even if you can fit the data.frame into memory, you still need enough RAM to operate on it.

Think about dimensionality of a quite small problem of climate data where a raster is 225 rows, 178 columns and 365 layers (size of a DAYMET climate tile). This will yield 14,618,250 observations, which is doable but, start thinking about real sized problems where, even with this same small dimension raster, over a 10 year observation period would expand to 146,182,500 observations. It is better to just operate on the rasters and keep things out of memory.

Comment: I used getValues() command but still I receive the same error.
"Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(object)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions"

Comment: What does your raster stack look like? If it is only a single layer netCDF then you have a vector and not a data.frame. A data.frame would indicate that you have a multi-raster stack where each column in your data.frame represents the values of a single raster.

Comment: How I can find the number of layers in the file?

Comment: Use nlayers(x) or just print the object, it will display information about the raster object including: nrows, ncols, nlayers, proj4string and extent.

Comment: It is only a single layer netCDF

Comment: Then you have a vector and not a data.frame, just remove the as.data.frame function surrounding getValues and it will work. You will add considerable memory overhead if you force it to be a data.frame because the object will then have to have row names.

Comment: So what is the best method to have these data in a excel sheet?